# Printing struct data from a singly-linked list

Tags: c, pointers, struct, printing, linked-list

I'm trying to build a singly-linked list using a struct with 2 data types: `char*` and `int`, as well as `next` to point to other nodes of course.

I have two functions: `addToList`, and `printList` as well as the main method to run everything.

What my code is supposed to do is add a node after the `head`, and check to see if another node with the same data has already been added. If so, it does not add the new node, while incrementing the `count` data of the already-linked node.

Then, `printList()` prints the `count` data and the `char*` data of each node.

The first issue is that my char comparison doesn't seem to be working, since duplicate nodes are still added. Then, my `printList` function does not print the char* data correctly. Here's my code (I made sure to comment it so it's easy to follow along):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Struct for node. Has an extra data variable to keep track of which node is next
// in a singly-linked list.
typedef struct node {
    char *str;
    unsigned int count;
    struct node *next;
} node;

// Creates a HEAD node with NULL data.
node *head = NULL;

// Adds a new node and populates the data.
struct node* addToList(struct node* Listptr, char* word){
    struct node* new = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 34);

    strcpy(new->str, word);

    new->count = 1;
    new->next = Listptr;

    // If the head is NULL, sets the new node as the head.
    if(head == NULL){
        head = new;
        return new;
    }

    // Sets a node iterator "cur" to the first position.
    node *cur = head;

    // Sets a node iterator to be one place behind cur.
    node *prev;

    // Loops through the linked list, in order to count the previous words and determine
    // if it is necessary to add another node.
    // Otherwise, it sets cur to the next node, and prev to the node cur was just at.
    while(cur != NULL){
        if(cur->str == new->str){
            cur->count++;
            new = NULL;
            return new;
        } else{
            prev = cur;
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    }

    // Checks to see if cur is NULL, if so, sets the previous node.next to the one we're adding.
    if(cur == NULL){
        prev->next = new;
        return new;
    }
}

// Prints out the count and word values of each node.
void printList(){
    node* cur = head;
    while(cur != NULL){
        printf("%d %c\n", cur->count, cur->str);
        cur = cur->next;
    }
}

int main() {

    node* Z = NULL;

    char *a = "hello";
    char *b = "world.";
    char *c = "hello";

    addToList(Z, a);
    addToList(Z, b);
    addToList(Z, c);

    printList(Z);

    return 0;
}
```

I expect to get:

```
2 hello
1 world
```

But in the console, I get:

```
1 l
1 (weird symbol)
1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `==` to compare strings rather use `strcmp()`.

Change `if (cur->str == new->str)` to this:

`if (strcmp(cur->str, new->str) == 0)`

Read this to know more on string compare: [How do I properly compare strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings)